# Copying rows from one DataGridView to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written an application that is connected to SQL database in C#.There are two forms.

I have a DataGrid in the first form. There are those columns like ID,AD,SOYAD in Datagridview.

I have a DataGrid in the second form(frm4) and there are those columns like ID,AD,SOYAD in Datagridview.

I put ContextMenuStrip in the first DataGridView.

My question is:I want to add to second DataGridView those rows which are choosen in the first DataGridView.

```
  frm4.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
  frm4.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
  frm4.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

I only can add one row with upper code. But,I want to add  multiple rows. I'm using below code for that. But, it's not working.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
      frm4.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      frm4.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      frm4.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: I  just noticed that this is tagged asp.net - is this correct? Because, the DataGridView is a Winform and not a Webforms control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume this is windows form application

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView2.DataSource != null)
    {
        this.dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
    }
    else
    {
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The following code works, though it can probably be improved. Also, you might want to take a step back and instead look at your datasource for the grid. If you are using a binding source for example you should be able to copy that and create the source for the second grid from there.

```
//to copy the rows you need to have created the columns:
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
{                
    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
}

//then you can copy the rows values one by one (working on the selectedrows collection)
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add(r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
    foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[o.ColumnIndex].Value = o.Value;
    }            
}
```

Comment: I was trying to get stuff from selected rows by foreach and doing `var` instead of `DataGridViewRow`, got a little bit angry that there are no methods and all, but it was treated as object. So this code helped me. VoteUp ;) **kids don't do `var` without thinking!**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Add method of the DataGridView. At this moment you're overwriting whatever value is on the first row. By using the Add method you add an extra row to the DataGridView.