# copy multiple row selected datagridview to another datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports

how  to Copy Contents in one `DataGridview` to another `DataGridview`
I want to select many rows in `DataGridview` and copy to another `DataGridview` then print it by Crystal Report.

Comment: tnx for reply 
nothing yet ....
i  have filtered data in datagridview i want to select that rows and copy it another datagridview then print by crystal report
is there other way to do it

Comment: Try this 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891267/copying-rows-from-one-datagridview-to-another

I hope this help for your poject. :-)

Comment: tnx brother i did 
so now how to print it with crystal report ...?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that

```
 //First create a crystal report then
 // you would create it's object
 crpLetter crp = new crpLetter();
 //set your dataset to report
 crp.SetDataSource(dsSrNoDigiTech);
 //create another from and drop Crystal Report Viewer on it.
 FrmReportViewer frm = new FrmReportViewer();
 //assign the Crystal Report to it's viewer
 frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crp;
 //this will print the report 
 frm.crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();
```