# How to move selected rows from one datagridview to another datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I tried this code to move selected rows from datagridview2 to datagridview1.But when I clicked to add button to move selected rows from datagridview2. And it also added to datagridview 2.But an error occurred through exception which is "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**".How to solve this. My code as follows

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                bool checkedCell = (bool)dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value;
                if (checkedCell == true)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I need to do this.But data should load by clicking load button
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying rows from one DataGridView to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891267/copying-rows-from-one-datagridview-to-another)

Comment: is it possible for you to provide more detail on the exception? which line  is it thrown? etc.

Comment: @AntiqTech its run foreachloop onece and throw the exception in "bool checkedCell = (bool)dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value;"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer selected rows from one datagridview to another in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724698/how-to-transfer-selected-rows-from-one-datagridview-to-another-in-c)

Comment: _bool checkedCell = (bool)dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value;_ Shouldn't that be `bool checkedCell = (bool)row.Cells[0].Value;` ? Also: The code you show is not moving but copying.

Comment: @Adam it seems that you get exception because dataGridView2.Rows[n] is null. From the picture you added, it's clear that datagridviews have different numbers of rows. You are adding a new row, let's say 10th; other datagridview may not have a 10th row and even it has, that would be the incorrect row to check. As TaW pointed out in the previous comment, changing it to  row.Cells[0].Value should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when you add row in datagridview2 you must set value of boolean column as same as :

```
  dataGridView2.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", false);
```

other solution for do that:

```
      this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList())
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value, row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value);
        }
```